# Use the same subquery 2 times in the same query with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table representing friendships that looks like the following

```
+--------+--------+
| user_1 | user_2 |
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 5      |
| 2      | 67     |
| 3      | 23     |
| ...    | ...    |
+--------+--------+
```

I want to create a procedure to retrieve friends of friends (but direct friends can't be included in the results). I achieved this by doing the following:
(let's say we want friends of friends of user 5)

```
SELECT user_2
FROM friends
WHERE user_1 IN (
    SELECT user_2
    FROM friends
    WHERE user_1=5
) AND user_2 NOT IN (
    SELECT user_2
    FROM friends
    WHERE user_1=5
)
```

But the repetition annoys me.  How can I do the same without redundancy?

I know the answer is simple but I can't put my finger on it. I tried using aliases without any success. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to this works for me:

```
SELECT user_2
FROM friends,
(SELECT user_2 FROM friends WHERE user_1=5) USER2Alias
WHERE user_1 IN (USER2Alias.user_2) AND user_2 NOT IN (USER2Alias.user_2)
```

Comment: I forgot ".user2" on the alias, thats why it wasn't working thanks!